# Linear interpolation of three 3D points in 3D space

Tags: c++, matlab, math, linear-algebra, linear-interpolation

I have three 3D points like `p1(x1,y1,z1)`, `p2(x2,y2,z2)`, `p3(x3,y3,z3)`.
I have another point, but I know only `x`, `y` value of that point like `p4(x4,y4,Z)`, in which `Z` is the value I like to compute.

I am sure `p4(x4,y4)` point is inside a triangle formed by `p1(x1,y1)`, `p2(x2,y2)`, `p3(x3,y3)` by checking with delaunay triangulation approach. How can I compute `Z` value of point `p4`? I like to implement it in C programming. Actually I am trying to implement `griddata` in MATLAB.

Thanks

Comment: U need to provide more information, p1(x1,y1),p2(x2,y2),p3(x3,y3) are they the same points as the 3D points ? Or they are the p1,p2,p3 projections to xy plane ?

Comment: yes they are x,y plane points of 3D points.

Comment: Is that Barycentric Coordinates interpolation?

Comment: ALso, C or C++? (You say C, but you tag it as C++)

Comment: z can have multiple solutions. For example, say the known points are (0, 10, 0,) (0, 10, 10) (0, 0, 10) and you know the 4th point as (0, 5, z ), then z can have a set of values from 5 to 10.

Comment: This is looking for the intersection of a plane and a line. As @AbhishekBansal notices, that may have an infinite number of solutions, or it may have zero when the two are parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can express P4 coordinates in the P1P2P3 vector basis.

```
x4 = x1 + A * (x2 - x1) + B * (x3 - x1)
y4 = y1 + A * (y2 - y1) + B * (y3 - y1)
```

This is easy-to-solve linear equation system. You have to find A and B coefficients, then use them to calculate z-coordinate

```
z4 = z1 + A * (z2 - z1) + B * (z3 - z1)
```

Comment: Yeah it is same as Barycentric Coordinates interpolation.

Comment: @MBo: Perhaps due to the gratuitous complexity of solving a 2x2 system when the value can be computed directly?

Comment: @DanielKO This system may be solved with pen and paper or with Matlab

Comment: @DanielKO: that's not reason to downvote; it's a valid solution, that I would say has equivalent complexity to your approach.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote it, as it's a valid answer; it's just a bit indirect.

Answer (score 7):

`p1`, `p2`, `p3` define a plane. You can represent it by a point and a normal. For instance, `P=p1`, `N=(p2-P) x (p3-P)` (that is, N = cross product of `p1p2` and `p1p3`).

Now for p4 to be in the same plane, it satisfies the plane equation:

```
  (p4-P) · N = 0  %// dot product
⇒ (x4-x1)*N.x + (y4-y1)*N.y + (z4-z1)*N.z = 0
```

Re-arranging:

```
z4 = z1 - ((x4-x1)*N.x + (y4-y1)*N.y)/ N.z
```

No linear system to solve, you just need a cross product.

Comment: +1, but write out the solution to the linear system and you'll find the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is to support both MBo's and Konstantin's answers. Please don't accept this question, but one of the others.

This is how you would implement a solution in MATLAB:

```
%// Your known 3 points
p1 = [ 1 10  0]';
p2 = [-1 10 10]';
p3 = [ 0  0 10]';

%// your 4th target point
p4 = [0 5  NaN]';

%// Difference matrix/vector
A = [p2-p1  p3-p1];
b = p4-p1;

%// Compute solution
p4(end) = p1(end) + A(3,:)*(A(1:2,:)\b(1:2));
```

Now, in C++, the mere fact of including the relevant `eigen` libraries blows up the executable size rather spectacularly. What `eigen` is capable of is complete overkill for this simple 2x2 system.

So I wouldn't go as far as resort to `eigen`, unless you have tons of other linear algebra things to do. It is a simple 2x2 system, which is easy enough to solve by hand.

Just [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) it; see DanielKO's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical problem here is to solve the following system of equations

```
p1 + a * (p2 - p1) + b * (p3 - p1) = (x4, y4, z4)
```

or equivalently

```
 (x1,y1,z1) + a * (x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1) + b * (x3-x1, y3-y1, z3-z1) = (x4, y4, z4)
```

for a, b, and z4.

To solve it in C/C++, you could either implement the Gauss algo (see also the Numerical Recipes book, it is available online), or use Linear Algebra libraries, such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), or others.

Remark: the approach is the same regardless if the point `(x4, y4)` lies within the triangle `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)`, or not.

Comment: thanks. But if (x4,y4) lies inside the three points, the approach is the same. Is it?

Comment: @batuman: indeed. If it were to lie *outside* the triangle, it would be called *extrapolation* :)

Comment: Solvable, yes, but that does not mean it always has a solution.

Comment: @MSalters: I don't see the difference between "is solvable" and "has a solution", but you are right in that it does not always have a solution. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Konstantin: Easiest to see with the roots a second degree polynomial. Always solvable, possibly one solution, but can also have 0 or 2 solutions.

Comment: @MSalters: Still don't get what you mean by "solvable". How can an equation be always solvable if it can have 0 solutions? What is your definition of "solvable"?

Comment: @Konstantin: An equation is solvable if there exists an algorithm to produce all its solutions, or prove that there are no solutions. `erf(x)=1/3` is not solvable, even though a solution exists. `x*x = -1` is solvable, precisely because we can prove no solution exists.